# PowerBi Matrix - display subtotals as averages, ignore blank cells

Tags: matrix, powerbi, measure

I have a  measure using DIVIDE function, that combines two other measures based on columns from different tables.
The matrix shows averages in row subtotals automatically.
However, it is not clear to me how to prevent it from counting in blank cells when calculating averages.

I can't find solution anywhere online, even though it seems like a simple problem.

[image]

---

```
% of Full Time = CALCULATE (DIVIDE([Actual Hours Heatmap], [Heatmap Capacity]))

Measure from source 1:
Heatmap Capacity = ROUND (calculate( sum('Workday Target per CC'[Hour Target]) * sum('Employee Mapping'[eMPLOYEE Count])), 2)

Measure from source 2:
Actual Hours Heatmap = ROUND (sum(Actuals Input[Hours ACT]),2)
```

- AVERAGEX function
- FILTER function
- Rounding
- Filter - measure is not 0 and not blank

Answer (score 0):

Measures are recalculated for each cell.  The total isn't an average-of-averages; it's the measure calculated without any active filter on Area.